# pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR: cache lookup failed for type 19

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

i use the slony for replication of postgresql database. it work fine some day.
After i use the slony command to delete the replication node, pg_dump does not work, the error message is:
pg_dump: schema with OID 73033 does not exist

Then i delete the name space of slony in  pg_namespace, and pg_dump does not work.
So i delete the data of the name space in pg_class, pg_type, the command is:
DELETE FROM pg_class where relnamespace=73033
DELETE FROM pg_type where relnamespace=73033

i got the error message:
pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  cache lookup failed for type 19

How to fix it? How to recovery the database?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restarting Postgresql after the change? Other seem to have fixed it that way as it clears the cache and is simple to do:

http://lists.slony.info/pipermail/slony1-general/2010-February/010361.html

Hope it as simple as that, but you have probably already tried that.

// John